# Linear Algebra proof with column space

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are two $m\times n$ matrices, then
the column space of $A$ is contained in the column space of $B$
if and only if $A=BC$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $C$.

So far I have that the rank of A equals the rank of BC and used the rank nullity theorem to show that the rank of BC equals the dimension of A plus. the nullity of A

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have that column space of $A$ given by linear combination is $\sum \alpha a_j$, with $a_j$ the collumns of $A$.If the column space of $A$ is in  $B$ for all column $a_j$ we have $a_j=\sum b_ic_{ij}$. See, we have the coeficients of each $a_j$ column of $A$ givem by lines $B$, the rank of lines is the same of columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $B$ have columns $b_1,\dots,b_n$. Let $C$ have columns $c_1,\dots,c_n$, and entries $c_{ij}$.  We note that
$$
BC = [B c_1 \cdots B c_n]
$$
and that
$$
B c_k = \sum_{j=1}^n c_{jk} b_j 
$$
which is in the column space of $B$, so that each of the columns of $BC$ are in the column space of $B$.  How can we do this "backwards"?